# How to create border any widget in pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk

I am trying to create one UI using python(PyGTK). I have one vbox. I have put eventbox as its parent. I want a visible border for the vbox or the eventbox. I want the border in red color. I tried modify_fg but its changing the whole. So kindly tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the gtk version that are you using???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Gtk3 (which you should at this point) you can use css to theme your widgets, something like:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class ColorSample(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self, application_id="org.app.ColorSample")

        style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
        css = '''
        #MainWindow { background-color: #F00; }
        '''
        style_provider.load_from_data(css)

        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
                                    style_provider,
                                    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    def do_activate(self):
        main_window = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        main_window.set_name('MainWindow')
        main_window.props.border_width = 4

        button = Gtk.Button("Doing Nothing")
        main_window.add(button)

        self.add_window(main_window)
        main_window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        main_window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    colorsample = ColorSample()
    colorsample.run(None)
```